# ImageGrab.grab(bbox) is not grabbing the correct size. Am I using bbox correctly?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I am trying to use ImageGrab to grab a certain portion of the screen but it is not grabbing the entire area set by bbox.

To make sure I am using bbox correctly I tried to simply capture the entire screen using the bbox parameter from the ImageGrab method.

I used both PyAutoGUI and Tkinter to verify the size of my display (both show my screen width as 1680 and my screen height as 1050) and then used those dimensions in the bbox parameter. However, when I do this, it only captures a small portion of the screen, as shown below:

[image]

When I use Image.grab() with no parameters, it captures the entire screen with no issues:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image, ImageOps
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

print(screen_width)
print(screen_height)

print(pyautogui.size())

ImageGrab.grab().show()
ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height)).show()
```

Can you please explain how to use the bbox parameter if I am not using it correctly?

Comment: Are you on a Mac with pixel doubling? If so, click **Apple** menu, **About this Mac**, **Displays** and check your screen resolution.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes! Thank you for pointing that out. About this Mac says that my display is actually 2880 x 1800. What is pixel doubling and how do I apply it in situations like this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how the designers/authors envisage that you deal with it - I just know it happens :-) If anyone can add any useful inputs, please ping my username too!